# Collection Test with StopWatch

Tags: java, collections, stopwatch

I'm trying to measure the elapsed time of a collection with 115 items.
My problem is that I can measure the elapsed time only when I am debuging and exactly set a breakpoint by using  `StopWatch.stop();`
When i run my test normal the value of `StopWatch.stop`is `0`, although it is a long-value. First I thought that my collection is to small, but this elapsed time should be passed as long-value.

```
//   times-collection will be initialised somewhere else
//---------------------------------------------------------------
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    final StopWatch stopwatchA = new StopWatch();
    final StopWatch stopwatchB = new StopWatch();
    Iterator<String> iterator = times.iterator();

    stopwatchA.start();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        if (iterator.next().equals("XXX")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    stopwatchA.stop();
    stopwatchB.start();
    for (String tzd : times) {

        if (tzd.equals("XXX")) {                
            break;
        }          
    }
    stopwatchB.stop();

    if(stopwatchA.getTime() < stopwatchB.getTime()){
        System.out.println("ITERATOR IS FASTER: iterator: " + estimatedTimeIterator + " FOR-TIME: " + estimatedTimeFor);
    }else if(stopwatchA.getTime() > stopwatchB.getTime()){
        System.out.println("FOR IS FASTER: iterator: " + estimatedTimeIterator + " FOR-TIME: " + estimatedTimeFor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which StopWatch you are using ? Is it Spring ?

Comment: You can use this "chronograph" i wrote using nanotime: https://github.com/marcolopes/dma/blob/master/org.dma.java/src/org/dma/java/util/Chronograph.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopwatch from Standard Libraries uses internally System.currentTimeMillis()
For a collection with 115 items it is perfectly possible to have less than 1ms between stopwatchA.start() and stopwatchA.stop()
Use System.nanoTime() instead.